# Tradução de código de MySQL para PostgreSQL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

Preciso converter uma página MySQL em comandos do PostgreSQL, mas já revirei a internet procurando os comandos semelhantes e sintaxe do PostgreSQL, e não obtive sucesso.

Alguns comandos não existem para PostgreSQL e são declarados junto com outros, e por aí vai.

Se alguém puder ajudar, seria maravilhoso para mim.

Código:

```
<?php
//utilização de namespaces
namespace Mysql {
    //declaração de variáres globais
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_NAME', 'acesso');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

    class mysql {
        var $db, $conn;
        public function __construct($server, $database, $username, $password) {
            $this->conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
            $this->db = mysql_select_db($database, $this->conn);
        }
        /**
         * Função de seleção dos registros da tabela
         * @param string $tabela tabela onde será buscado os registros
         * @param string $colunas string contendo as colunas separadas
por virgula para seleção, se null busca por todas *
         */
        public function select($tabela, $colunas = "*", $where = "1=1") {
            $sql = "SELECT $colunas FROM $tabela $where";
            $result = $this->executar($sql);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $return[] = $row;
            }
            return $return;
        }

        /**
         * Função para inserir dados na tabela
         * @param array $dados Array contendo os dados a serem inseridos
         * @param string $tabela tabela que será inserido os dados
         * @return boolean verdadeiro ou falso
         */
        public function insert($tabela, $dados) {

            foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
                $keys[] = $key;
                $insertvalues[] = '\'' . $value . '\'';
            }
            $keys = implode(',', $keys);
            $insertvalues = implode(',', $insertvalues);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela ($keys) VALUES ($insertvalues)";
            return $this->executar($sql);
        }
        private function executar($sql) {
            $return_result = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);
            if ($return_result) {
                return $return_result;
            } else {
                $this->sql_error($sql);
            }
        }
        private function sql_error($sql) {
            echo mysql_error($this->conn) . '<br>';
            die('error: ' . $sql);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Posso editar livremente e substituir esse *namespace* MySQL por esse *namespace* PostgreSQL? Ou é uma função MySQL?

Na parte de `mysql_select_db:` como ficaria na linguagem do PostgreSQL? Não encontrei a equivalência.

Comment: É só trocar pelas funções pg_*, segue a [lista de comandos](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php). Se tiver alguma dúvida especifica edite a pergunta :). Pode usar o PDO também, serve para MySQL e PostgresSQL.

Comment: A forma como está a pergunta não possui nenhuma dúvida especifica, pede a reescrita do código.

Comment: @rray é o que estou tentando fazer. Mas como disse, sou bem leigo e é um tanto quanto difícil pra mim, pois não se trata de simplesmente mudar onde está escrito mysql para pg. Algumas funções não existem no postgres, pois são feitas de outra forma. Quando o PDO, estou me informando sobre. Nunca tinha ouvido falar.

Comment: No lugar de `mysql_select_db()` use apenas o `pg_connect()` a diferença é que você já informa o banco de dados, veja uma exemplo: `$con = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=nome_do_banco user=usuario password=senha");`

Comment: Sugiro que comece fazendo um teste, crie um arquivo a parte, com a conexão do postgres, depois faça um consulta usando o `pg_query()` e obtenha o resultado com o `pg_fetch_*()` quando estiver funcionando e um pouco mais familizarado com as função comece a alterar sua classe. Se precisar crie outra pergunta com o código e a mensagem de erro. O primeiro passo as vezes é errar mesmo, assim corrige o problema e vai em frente.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Além do [PDO](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-php-pdo/24973) citado pelo colega, também vou recomendar como opção um framework ORM como [TORM](http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/torm-um-orm-simples-para-php/) ou [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Todos estes abstraem a parte do banco de dados tornando o mesmo código compatível com qualquer banco sem grandes alterações.

Comment: não consegui usar nenhum destes. Acho que não entendi a 'essência'. Sigo tentando editar o código para a linguagem postgresql.

Comment: O mais parecido com o seu modelo é o PDO que usa mesma "essência" do seu estilo de código. Já os frameworks ORM usam uma "essência" diferente. Uma vez que você vai ter que reformular todo o seu código, acredito que compensa usar o PDO. Além deste citado, tem vários tutoriais na internet.